# What is this web service invocation code, what is happening exactly?

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsurlconnection

The following Code does call a web service, yet I do not fully understand it's structure.

```
NSError *error;
NSData *postData = [NSJSONSerialization dataWithJSONObject: requestData options:0 error:&error];
NSString *postLength = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%lu", (unsigned long)[postData length]];
NSMutableURLRequest *request = [[NSMutableURLRequest alloc] init];
[request setURL:url];
[request setHTTPMethod:@"POST"];
[request setValue:@"application/json" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Type"];
[request setValue:@"private" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Cache-Control"];
[request setValue:@"Microsoft-IIS/7.5" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Server"];
[request setValue:@"Basic realm='TimeBoxWebAPI'" forHTTPHeaderField:@"WWW-Authenticate"];

[request setValue:postLength forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Length"];
[request setValue:@"application/json" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Accept"];
[request setHTTPBody:postData];

NSOperationQueue *queue = [[NSOperationQueue alloc] init];
[NSURLConnection sendAsynchronousRequest:request 
                                   queue:queue         
                       completionHandler:^(NSURLResponse *response, NSData *data, NSError *error) 
{
    [[UIApplication sharedApplication] setNetworkActivityIndicatorVisible:NO];
    if ([data length] >0 && error == nil){
        dispatch_queue_t myQueue = dispatch_queue_create("My Queue", DISPATCH_QUEUE_SERIAL);

            dispatch_async(myQueue, ^{

                [self parseGetSchedulingData:data];
                dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
                     [[UIApplication sharedApplication] setNetworkActivityIndicatorVisible:NO];
                         [tableHolidays reloadData];
                         [refreshControl endRefreshing];

                     if(activityIndicator.isAnimating)
                     {
                         [activityIndicator stopAnimating];
                         [activityIndicator removeFromSuperview];
                     }
                 });
             });
         }
         else if ([data length] == 0 && error == nil){
             NSLog(@"Empty Response, not sure why?");

             [[[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle: nil
                                         message:@"Error while trying to log in. Please try later"
                                        delegate:nil
                               cancelButtonTitle:@"OK"
                               otherButtonTitles:nil] show];

             dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
                 [[UIApplication sharedApplication] setNetworkActivityIndicatorVisible:NO];
                 if(activityIndicator.isAnimating)
                 {
                     [activityIndicator stopAnimating];
                     [activityIndicator removeFromSuperview];
                 }
             });

         }


         else if (error != nil){
             NSLog(@"%@", error.description);
             dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
                 [[UIApplication sharedApplication] setNetworkActivityIndicatorVisible:NO];
                 if(activityIndicator.isAnimating)
                 {
                     [activityIndicator stopAnimating];
                     [activityIndicator removeFromSuperview];
                 }
             });
         }
     }];
}
```

Especially, I'm unsure about what the calls to `setValue:forHTTPHeaderField:` and `sendAsynchronousRequest:queue:completion:` do exactly.

Comment: What exactly do you not understand about this rather lengthy example?

Comment: what is NSURLConnection
     sendAsynchronousRequest:request
     queue:queue
     completionHandler:^(NSURLResponse *response,
                         NSData *data,
                         NSError *error) {

Answer (score 2):

As [the documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSURLConnection_Class/#//apple_ref/occ/clm/NSURLConnection/sendAsynchronousRequest:queue:completionHandler:) says,

> ## Parameters
>
> ### request
>
> The URL request to load. The request object is deep-copied as part of the initialization process. Changes made to request after this method returns do not affect the request that is used for the loading process.
>
> ### queue
>
> The operation queue to which the handler block is dispatched when the request completes or failed.
>
> ### handler
>
> The handler block to execute.
>
> ## Discussion
>
> If the request completes successfully, the data parameter of the handler block contains the resource data, and the error parameter is nil. If the request fails, the data parameter is nil and the error parameter contain information about the failure.
>
> If authentication is required in order to download the request, the required credentials must be specified as part of the URL. If authentication fails, or credentials are missing, the connection will attempt to continue without credentials. If the request finishes with a 401 Unauthorized status code, the response parameter is nil, the data parameter contains the resource data, and the error parameter is an NSError with the NSURLErrorUserCancelledAuthentication code in the NSURLErrorDomain error domain.
>
> ## Availability
>
> Available in iOS 5.0 and later.
>
> Deprecated in iOS 9.0.

Please let me know if something is still unclear.

**Edit 1**:

Regarding

```
[request setValue:@"application/json" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Type"]; 
[request setValue:@"private" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Cache-Control"];
[request setValue:@"Microsoft-IIS/7.5" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Server"];
[request setValue:@"Basic realm='TimeBoxWebAPI'" forHTTPHeaderField:@"WWW-Authenticate"];
[request setValue:postLength forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Length"];
[request setValue:@"application/json" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Accept"];
[request setHTTPBody:postData];
```

Those set different values for [HTTP header fields](http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec14.html) and finally the HTTP body on the request.

Comment: what is this [request setValue:@"application/json" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Type"];
     [request setValue:@"private" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Cache-Control"];
     [request setValue:@"Microsoft-IIS/7.5" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Server"];
      [request setValue:@"Basic realm='TimeBoxWebAPI'" forHTTPHeaderField:@"WWW-Authenticate"];

    [request setValue:postLength forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Length"];
    [request setValue:@"application/json" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Accept"];
    [request setHTTPBody:postData];